# Debian bond with tagged and native VLANs

Tags: networking, debian, vlan, network-interface

I have a server with 4 interfaces(eno1..4) bonded together. So far so good.

With the VLANS in the config, when I start networking services, it return an error:

```
$ service networking status
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-09-04 11:04:11 -03; 7min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 1989 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2180 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2175 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2180 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

If I comment auto bond0.20/30 and restart networking, I got no error. But If I ifup bond0 20, I got an error:

```
$ ifup bond0.20
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup: failed to bring up bond0.20
```

Here is my conf:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Bonding interfaces

allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

allow-hotplug eno2
iface eno2 inet manual

allow-hotplug eno3
iface eno3 inet manual

allow-hotplug eno4
iface eno4 inet manual

# Main bonding interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address 10.10.0.1
        gateway 10.10.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        dns-nameservers 10.10.0.254
        dns-search mydomain.local
        bond-mode 802.3ad
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-downdelay 200
        bond-updelay 200
        bond-lacp-rate 1
        bond_xmit_hash_policy layer2+3
        bond-slaves eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4

auto bond0.20
iface bond0.20 inet static
        address 10.20.0.1
        gateway 10.20.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto bond0.30
iface bond0.30 inet static
        address 10.30.0.1
        gateway 10.30.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

## EDIT

My new setup with bridges:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    slaves eno1 eno2
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-downdelay 200
    bond-updelay 200
    bond-lacp-rate 1
    bond_xmit_hash_policy layer2+3

auto bond0.20
iface bond0.20 inet manual

auto br20
iface br20 inet static
    address  192.168.100.1
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    network  192.168.100.0
    bridge_ports bond0.20
    bridge_maxwait 5
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

auto bond0.30
iface bond0.30 inet manual

auto br30
iface br30 inet static
    address  192.168.200.1
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    network  192.168.200.0
    bridge_ports bond0.30
    bridge_maxwait 5
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

It goes up, but return an error, show the service networking status isn't clean.

```
$ service networking status
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-09-04 20:08:38 -03; 29s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 923 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 902 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 923 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha ifup[923]: + [ meta = meta ]
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha ifup[923]: + exit 0
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha ifup[923]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ip
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha ifup[923]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha ifup[923]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/postfix
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha ifup[923]: run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 04 20:08:38 alpha systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: You need to find out where systemd is logging what's actually happened, as it doesn't show the issue here. It's likely accessed via some invocation of `journald` however I'm not a systemd user so can't advise further.

Comment: The problem is that when it tries to up the bond0.20, it says it already exists, and it does. I changed my setup a bit, to add bridges, as I'll need them in the KVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

My mistake, multiple `gateway` entries, should have only one!

Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did was:

Remove `auto` from vlans, added the following to the `bond0`:

```
 pre-up vconfig add bond0 20; vconfig add bond0 30
```

This way the vlans are created before the bond0 interface goes up.

Final config file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Bonding interfaces

allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

allow-hotplug eno2
iface eno2 inet manual

allow-hotplug eno3
iface eno3 inet manual

allow-hotplug eno4
iface eno4 inet manual

# Main bonding interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
        address 10.10.0.1
        gateway 10.10.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        dns-nameservers 10.10.0.254
        dns-search mydomain.local
        bond-mode 802.3ad
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-downdelay 200
        bond-updelay 200
        bond-lacp-rate 1
        bond_xmit_hash_policy layer2+3
        bond-slaves eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4
        pre-up vconfig add bond0 20; vconfig add bond0 30

iface bond0.20 inet static
        address 10.20.0.1
        gateway 10.20.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0

iface bond0.30 inet static
        address 10.30.0.1
        gateway 10.30.0.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: This solved the bond + vlan problem. But now I have bridges and it doesn't work anymore.